# Does PyAssimp only work with STL file-format?

Tags: python, cad, assimp

The Open Asset Import Library (short name: Assimp) is a portable Open-Source library to import various well-known 3D model formats in a uniform manner. I'm trying to use the Python Port PyAssimp, however I can only get it to work with the STL file format.
It says on the github page that Many ASSIMP features are missing in the Python Port, so I'm wondering if it is supposed to work only with STL (as assimp works with various CAD file formats).
When trying to import a file format that is not STL, I get the error message `pyassimp.errors.AssimpError: Could not import file!`.

[Assimp Website](https://www.assimp.org/index.php)
[Assimp GitHub](https://github.com/assimp/assimp)

Has someone experience in using the python port pyassimp?

Comment: I don't have experience with PyAssimp, but the supported formats may be helpful in determining which one you could try and use / convert to: https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/port/PyAssimp/pyassimp/formats.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all supported formats of the assimp-native-libs shall be supported by the port. The python package is only a small wrapper on top of the assimp-dlls. So all importers are implicitly provided.